# What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?

Tags: javascript, void

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loginlink">login</a>
```

I've seen such `href`s many times, but I don't know what exactly that means.

Comment: `javascript:` is one of the many URI schemes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme, like `data:`.

Comment: You can use just `href="javascript:"` for the same purpose. As stated in the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5237105/3075942), the `void(0)` part was originally intended for early versions of browsers where `javascript:` URI handling was different. But now I couldn't even find a version where the shorthand wouldn't work, at least IE7 handles this correctly.

Comment: I've also seen href="javascript://", is this better?

Comment: href="javascript://" is not working for me  void(0) works perfectly.

Comment: @sandip Which browser did you use back then? `href="javascript://"` and `href="javascript:void(0)"` are equivalent. `//` is a JS comment.

Comment: But why whould you want a link that does nothing? I've seen this many times, and it did exactly that, means it was a disfunctional page.

Answer (score 1290, accepted):

> The `void` operator evaluates the given
>   expression and then returns `undefined`.
>
> The `void` operator is often used merely
>   to obtain the `undefined` primitive
>   value, usually using “`void(0)`” (which
>   is equivalent to “`void 0`”). In these
>   cases, the global variable [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)
>   can be used instead (assuming it has
>   not been assigned to a non-default
>   value).

An explanation is provided here: [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

The reason you’d want to do this with the `href` of a link is that normally, a `javascript:` URL will redirect the browser to a plain text version of the result of evaluating that JavaScript. But if the result is `undefined`, then the browser stays on the same page. `void(0)` is just a short and simple script that evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: what does it mean when href is given a "undefined primitive value"?

Comment: "normally a javascript: url will redirect the browser to a plain text version of the result of evaluating that javascript. "

Can you make an example here?I've never seen such usage.

Comment: if your write a javascript function on onclick and if the javascript functin returns false then this false will be shown in the browser

Comment: And, isn't javascript:void() more convenient to achieve that goal?

Comment: An example of what phoenix is talking about is <a href="javascript: dosomething();">DO IT NOW! </a>. If dosomething returns false, then clicking the link will simply cause the browser to exit the page and display "false". However... <a href="javascript: dosomething(); void(0)">DO IT NOW! </a> avoids the problem. Go ahead and paste javascript: 1+1; into your browsers address bar. The browser should display "2"

Comment: @Breton ,thank you.Got it.

But why don't we use "javascript:void()",I mean,why is "0" needed here?

Comment: Because void is a unary operator. Void is not a value, nor is it a function. It needs a value to operate on to its right, or it will throw an error.

Comment: try looking in the error console? It definetely throws a syntax error. It's invalid javascript. Douglas crockford reccomends staying away from void because of the unary operator/function/value confusion is too costly to deal with.

Comment: read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1293130/1936980) below, it clarifies things beautifully.

Comment: may be, it can be simpler to use the
    javascript;

Comment: Maybe worth noting - undefined is not writable variable, as seen in first link of this answer.

Comment: What's wrong with "javascript:undefined", it seems to work in the same way.

Comment: Aside from whether it is right or wrong, this post does not really answer *how* `javascript:void(0)` style links work. Presumably, that is quite related to the question.

Comment: Although I almost always use `href="#"` (with the now available `e.preventDefault()`), why don't we all just style a span/p/div?  It seems much easier and less of a javascript hassle.  By what I have found, an "a" and a "span" are identical with defaults except for the color and the fact that "a" can contain a link.

Comment: "`void 0` is the smallest possible"... would it work using `[][0]`? It also evaluates to undefined. (this and `null` seems to work on Chrome, not sure on other browsers)

Comment: @Breton Not anymore on Microsoft Edge, it now blocks inline javascript, no matter in the URL box or in href attribute of <a>.

Comment: @BrunoLM I had the same thought, but `0[0]` is actually shorter, and also evaluates to undefined. It's also so much more readable than void(0) /s

Comment: When I typed `javascript:"<h1><a href=\"javascript:'Whoa'\">Surprise!!</a></h1>"` in my address bar, it was a small surprise that it rendered as html. An even bigger surprise was that the address bar stayed on the same page, even after clicking the link (Chrome only. Edge changes the address bar initially but not when clicking the link).

Comment: Void(0) is used to prevent the page from refreshing and parameter "zero" is passed while calling.

Void(0) is used to call another method without refreshing the page.

Comment: But `javascript:;` works too (no errors), and it's easy to understand that it means "do nothing". Why is it not used?

Comment: IMHO, I prefer `javascript:void(0)`  :D

Comment: @Jaketr00 You shouldn't use a span/p/div unless you also specify a tabindex. There are too many sites that do that, and it's annoying because the links get skipped in the tab order.

Answer (score 516):

In addition to the technical answer, `javascript:void` means the author is Doing It Wrong.

There is no good reason to use a `javascript:` pseudo-URL(*). In practice it will cause confusion or errors should anyone try things like ‘bookmark link’, ‘open link in a new tab’, and so on. This happens quite a lot now people have got used to middle-click-for-new-tab: it looks like a link, you want to read it in a new tab, but it turns out to be not a real link at all, and gives unwanted results like a blank page or a JS error when middle-clicked.

`<a href="#">` is a common alternative which might arguably be less bad. However you must remember to `return false` from your `onclick` event handler to prevent the link being followed and scrolling up to the top of the page.

In some cases there may be an actual useful place to point the link to. For example if you have a control you can click on that opens up a previously-hidden `<div id="foo">`, it makes some sense to use `<a href="#foo">` to link to it. Or if there is a non-JavaScript way of doing the same thing (for example, ‘thispage.php?show=foo’ that sets foo visible to begin with), you can link to that.

Otherwise, if a link points only to some script, it is not really a link and should not be marked up as such. The usual approach would be to add the `onclick` to a `<span>`, `<div>`, or an `<a>` without an `href` and style it in some way to make it clear you can click on it. This is what StackOverflow [did at the time of writing; now it uses `href="#"`].

The disadvantage of this is that you lose keyboard control, since you can't tab onto a span/div/bare-a or activate it with space. Whether this is actually a disadvantage depends on what sort of action the element is intended to take. You can, with some effort, attempt to mimic the keyboard interactability by adding a `tabIndex` to the element, and listening for a Space keypress. But it's never going to 100% reproduce the real browser behaviour, not least because different browsers can respond to the keyboard differently (not to mention non-visual browsers).

If you really want an element that isn't a link but which can be activated as normal by mouse or keyboard, what you want is a `<button type="button">` (or `<input type="button">` is just as good, for simple textual contents). You can always use CSS to restyle it so it looks more like a link than a button, if you want. But since it behaves like a button, that's how really you should mark it up.

(*: in site authoring, anyway. Obviously they are useful for bookmarklets. `javascript:` pseudo-URLs are a conceptual bizarreness: a locator that doesn't point to a location, but instead calls active code inside the current location. They have caused massive security problems for both browsers and webapps, and should never have been invented by Netscape.)

Comment: In addition to excellent post by @bobince: I've done some research a couple of months ago on cross-browser keyboard navigability of `href`s, including quirks and side effects; some of you might find it useful: http://jakub-g.github.com/accessibility/onclick/

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure I'm forming good habits. As someone new to js / frontend. What habit do you recommend I follow when making 'javascript triggering' links/buttons, no href or href='#'?

Comment: `<a href="#">` is better than `<span>` for accessibility reasons, so I'm glad SO has changed. But my preference is still for `<button type="button">`/`<input type="button">` + styling.

Comment: This is an opinion and doesn't answer the question. `void(0)` is needed in many cases; "#" is a hack that brings with it a whole host of problems (it would not work in the app I'm writing, that brought me to this page).

Comment: I agree with @feltwithe. Why force others to "Do it A Particular Way"? In 15 years of programming I am yet to see how the motto "it should always be done this way" doesn't lead people to a mess of their own making

Comment: void(0) is needed if you're using a CMS which only lets you edit the href values. So many programmers presume that others have complete control over their environment.

Comment: `href='#'` at-least opens a useful page in the new tab rather than a blank page.

Comment: Using the fragment-id is a bad idea from a UX perspective as it causes the document to jump to the top of the page unless `preventDefault` is used. Please don't do it in the case of an anchor being used as a button on a form.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: This is incorrect, you wouldn't be "doing it wrong" if you are using image maps, whose clickable bounds are specified polygonally and the "only" way to execute JavaScript would be by using # of JavaScript:void(0);

Comment: @Matth3w click events on `<area>` work fine. You can omit `href` completely. (Prior to HTML5, you'd've needed `nohref`, but either way works.) There is no reason to resort to `href=javascript:...` for image maps.

Comment: I'd say the worlds fair share of HTML coders have't moved to HTML5 for one reason or another...  WIth certain versions of IE as well as the latest version of Edge, the <A is required IMHO.

Comment: _“For example if you have a control you can click on that opens up a previously-hidden `<div id="foo">`, it makes some sense to use `<a href="#foo">` to link to it.”_ — You can even make it display without JS; only with CSS, using [`:target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target): `#foo{ display: none; } #foo:target{ display: unset; }`. Though closing it again may be a bit tricky.

Comment: In my experience, `<a href="#">` is the worst thing you can do because one of 2 things happen when the on-click script generates an error:  Either the scroll jumps to the top of the page--super annoying--or if the `<base>` tag is used the browser navigates to `/` and if you don't have persistent logging turned on to capture the error, you're left wondering what just happened.

Comment: @AufgeschissenerKunde: Which is exactly what happened on **this website** in some browsers just a few months ago...

Answer (score 151):

It means it’ll do nothing. It’s an attempt to have the link not ‘navigate’ anywhere. But it’s not the right way.

You should actually just `return false` in the `onclick` event, like so:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">hello</a>
```

Typically it’s used if the link is doing some ‘JavaScript-y’ thing. Like posting an AJAX form, or swapping an image, or whatever. In that case you just make whatever function is being called return `false`.

To make your website completely awesome, however, generally you’ll include a link that does the same action, if the person browsing it chooses not to run JavaScript.

```html
<a href="backup_page_displaying_image.aspx"
   onclick="return coolImageDisplayFunction();">hello</a>
```

Comment: href="#" will add a "#" to the url,which is ugly.

Comment: It not only adds # to the url but also takes the focus to the top of the form.

Comment: no no - return false will stop the default behavior, so the # will never appear

Comment: Phoenix and shore: return false will prevent the link from ever evaluating. It won't go anywhere, nor will it change focus to the top of the page.

Comment: Ok,but I still like the void version better,since it won't bother onclick attribute,all in a nutshell.

Comment: shore: that's your preference. but it's not the 'correct' way.

Comment: @silky, I'm just curious what makes it the 'correct' way? I'm not saying you're wrong, because I do it the way you've mentioned, but I do it just because thats the way I learned to do it. Is this actually based off a standard or something?

Comment: the javascript: url protocol is a defacto standard, not a real standard. So the href="#" onclick="return false;" is standards compliant while href="javascript:void(0)" is not, because there is no official standard that specifies what that should do.

Comment: On top of that, Douglas Crockford doesn't like void, so jslint will complain about it. Basically, since void is an operator, and not a value, it's confusing as hell, and spawns many questions such as this one. Better to avoid it altogether. haha.

Comment: Brandon: see brenton's responses. The way I recommend is the most supported and as I said in the second part of my post, in a 'proper' site you won't ever even use '#', because you'll be providing fallback systems to handle a lack of javascript.

Comment: +1 for including the *completely awesome* example. Even if you have no static HTML fall-back for what you're doing in JavaScript, you can always do something like `<a href="enableJavaScriptToSeeMyCompletelyAwesomeSite.html" onclick="completelyAwesome();return false;">`.

Comment: You should never ever ever `return false`, and you should rarely, if ever, use inline JavaScript. This answer was written 5 years ago when many now-accepted web design processes weren't invented yet, so these were seen as OK. Although I guess, even now, they aren't as bad as `href="javascript:void:0"`.

Comment: In event handlers, `return false;` does both `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`. It's usually better to be explicit. Perhaps I shouldn't have said "never ever", or maybe I should have said "never ever in production". Just be careful and be sure you are OK with doing both.

Answer (score 102):

It is a very popular method of adding JavaScript functions to HTML links.
For example: the `[Print]` links that you see on many webpages are written like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callPrintFunction()">Print</a>
```

Why do we need `href` while `onclick` alone can get the job done? Because when users hover over the text 'Print' when there's no `href`, the cursor will change to a caret (ꕯ) instead of a pointer (👆). Only having `href` on an `a` tag validates it as a hyperlink.

An alternative to `href="javascript:void(0);"`, is the use of `href="#"`. This alternative doesn't require JavaScript to be turned on in the user's browser, so it is more compatible.

Comment: neither does anything useful if javascript is turned off.

Comment: You don't need `href` to get the pointing hand cursor; all it takes is a bit of CSS.

Comment: Why would you not put the JavaScript function in the href instead the onclick?

Comment: I agree with @Sid - if you're using it to trigger a javascript function then `<a href="javascript:callPrintFunction()">` is cleaner (although it should probably be a `button` rather than an `a`nchor if it doesn't actually take you anywhere).

Comment: `href="#"` can lead to nasty surprises - like aborted xhr requests, that happen to be called on a click to that link. I recently had a hard time debugging a website which aborted oidc login requested, if the user happened to be in an address that wasn't the root of the site. `#` href caused it to reload the address before xhr request got completed.

Answer (score 99):

There is a *huge* difference in the behaviour of `#` vs `javascript:void(0);`.

`#` scrolls you to the top of the page but `javascript:void(0);` does not.

This is very important if you are coding dynamic pages because the user does not want to go back to the top when they click a link on the page.

Comment: @Salvin: The *scroll-to-top-of-page* behavior can be suppressed by returning `false` to the event handler: `onclick="doSomething();return false;"`, or if `doSomething()` returns `false`, you can use `onclick="return doSomething();"`.

Comment: @GrantWagner - Or, 5 years later, `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: You might want to edit/delete this answer since `"#"` does *not* scroll to the top when you return false.

Comment: @Navin you are correct, but that is now an outdated practice. The comment by trysis is considered the correct way now.

Comment: @trysis Or, in inline html, use `event` for `e`. The `event` variable is available inside inline html `onclick` handler. `<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();">...</a>`

Answer (score 53):

You should always have an href on your **a** tags. Calling a JavaScript function that returns 'undefined' will do just fine. So will linking to '#'.

Anchor tags in Internet Explorer 6 without an href do not get the `a:hover` style applied.

Yes, it is terrible and a minor crime against humanity, but then again so is Internet Explorer 6 in general.

I hope this helps.

Internet Explorer 6 is actually a major crime against humanity.

Answer (score 46):

It's worth mentioning that you'll sometimes see `void 0` when checking for undefined, simply because it requires fewer characters.

For example:

```js
if (something === undefined) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Compared to:

```js
if (something === void 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Some minification methods replace `undefined` with `void 0` for this reason.

Comment: One notable example is TypeScript ([live example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20fn(value%3A%20number%20%3D%207)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%20*%202%3B%0D%0A%7D)), which compiles default parameter values to checks against `void 0`. The 3 character difference adds up quickly when lots of methods are using default param values.

Comment: "Some minification methods replace undefined with void 0 for this reason." Finally I understand it! Thanks @squall for the thorough answer.

Comment: @ΛRYΛN That is not correct. Your code also does something on `false`, `0`, `""` and a bunch of other things.

Answer (score 34):

Usage of `javascript:void(0)` means that the author of the HTML is misusing the anchor element in place of the button element.

> Anchor tags are often abused with the onclick event to create
>   pseudo-buttons by setting href to "#" or "javascript:void(0)" to
>   prevent the page from refreshing. These values cause unexpected
>   behavior when copying/dragging links, opening links in a new
>   tabs/windows, bookmarking, and when JavaScript is still downloading,
>   errors out, or is disabled. This also conveys incorrect semantics to
>   assistive technologies (e.g., screen readers). In these cases, it is
>   recommended to use a `<button>` instead. In general you should only use
>   an anchor for navigation using a proper URL.

Source: [MDN's `<a>` Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: +1 for bringing up semantic html on an old question... Links go places, buttons do things - if we don't want it looking like a button, we should just clear the styling.

Comment: The big exception to this would be image maps, which may need to execute JavaScript; and since it is not a button, it is a link that has polygonal bounds, this is the "only" way.

Answer (score 28):

Web Developers use `javascript:void(0)` because it is the easiest way to prevent the default behavior of `a` tag. `void(*anything*)` returns `undefined` and it is a falsy value. and returning a falsy value is like `return false` in `onclick` event of `a` tag that prevents its default behavior.

**So I think `javascript:void(0)` is the simplest way to prevent the default behavior of `a` tag.**

Answer (score 23):

`void` is an operator that is used to return a `undefined` value so the browser will not be able to load a new page.

Web browsers will try and take whatever is used as a URL and load it unless it is a JavaScript function that returns null. For example, if we click a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript: alert('Hello World')">Click Me</a>
```

then an alert message will show up without loading a new page, and that is because `alert` is a function that returns a null value. This means that when the browser attempts to load a new page it sees null and has nothing to load.

An important thing to note about the void operator is that it requires a value and cannot be used by itself. We should use it like this:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a useless link</a>
```

Comment: I have seen people use javascript:null instead of void... but that's a problem. Chrome null works, in Firefox, it tries to load the page null. 
Glad you updated. Interesting bug.

Comment: I found some other uses in a codebase like the javascript:null but with javascript:null() which is undefined, so that works.

Comment: So basically it's like jquery's prevendDefault and return false?

Answer (score 20):

To understand this concept one should first understand the void operator in JavaScript.

The syntax for the void operator is: `void «expr»` which evaluates expr and returns undefined.

If you implement void as a function, it looks as follows:

```
function myVoid(expr) {
    return undefined;
}
```

This void operator has one important usage that is - discarding the result of an expression.

In some situations, it is important to return undefined as opposed to the result of an expression. Then void can be used to discard that result. One such situation involves javascript: URLs, which should be avoided for links, but are useful for bookmarklets. When you visit one of those URLs, many browsers replace the current document with the result of evaluating the URLs “content”, but only if the result isn’t undefined. Hence, if you want to open a new window without changing the currently displayed content, you can do the following:

```
javascript:void window.open("http://example.com/")
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying exactly what the argument to 'void' is for!  It wasn't clear in the other answers, only that "void takes an argument".

Comment: Good answer but one detail, the void implementation will be something like:         
  
 `function myVoid(expr) {
    expr();
    return undefined;
}`

You forgot add  **expr();**

Comment: @Juanma Menendez: not true. `expr` is already evaluated when `myVoid()` called (the *result* of that expression is passed as parameter)

Comment: @UdoG I am curious, how do you know that men? can you please explain.

Comment: @JuanmaMenendez: *expressions* in functions parameters are always evaluated before calling the function itself. Sorry, I have no document at hand that makes that clear but try yourself: `function() { alert("foo"); }` is a valid *expression*. `void(function() { alert("foo"); })`returns `undefined` and does **not** show the alert, whereas `myVoid(function() { alert("foo"); })` does (in your version, not the one of *Gopal Yadav*).

Answer (score 20):

A link must have an `href` target to be specified to enable it to be a usable display object.

Most browsers will not parse advanced JavaScript in the `href` of an `<a>` element, for example:

```html
<a href="javascript:var el = document.getElementById('foo');">Get element</a>
```

Because the `href` tag in most browsers does not allow whitespace or will convert whitespace to `%20` (the HEX code for space), the JavaScript interpreter will run into multiple errors.

So if you want to use an `<a>` element's `href` to execute inline JavaScript, you must specify a valid value for `href` first that isn't too complex (doesn't contain whitespace), and then provide the JavaScript in an event attribute tag like `onClick`, `onMouseOver`, `onMouseOut`, etc.

The typical answer is to do something like this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="var el = document.getElementById('foo');">Get element</a>
```

This works fine but it makes the page scroll to the top because the `#` in the `href` tells the browser to do this.

Placing a `#` in the `<a>` element's `href` specifies the root anchor, which is by default the top of the page, but you can specify a different location by specifying the `name` attribute inside an `<a>` element.

```html
<a name="middleOfPage"></a>
```

You can then change your `<a>` element's `href` to jump to `middleOfPage` and execute the JavaScript in the `onClick` event:

```html
<a href="#middleOfPage" onclick="var el = document.getElementById('foo');">Get element</a>
```

There will be many times where you do not want that link jumping around, so you can do two things:

```html
<a href="#thisLinkName" name="thisLinkCame" onclick="var elem = document.getElementById('foo');">Get element</a>
```

Now it will go nowhere when clicked, but it could cause the page to re-centre itself from its current viewport.

The best way to use in-line javascript using an `<a>` element's `href`, but without having to do any of the above is `JavaScript:void(0);`:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="var el = document.getElementById('foo');">Get element</a>
```

This tells the browser no to go anywhere, but instead execute the `JavaScript:void(0);` function in the `href` because it contains no whitespace, and will not be parsed as a URL. It will instead be run by the compiler.

`void` is a keyword which, when supplied with a parameter of `0` returns `undefined`, which does not use any more resources to handle a return value that would occur without specifying the `0` (it is more memory-management/performance friendly).

The next thing that happens is the `onClick` gets executed. The page does not move, nothing happens display-wise.

Comment: +1 for explaining all of the different ways an anchor like this _could_ be handled. I'm of the opinion though, that an `<a>` element _must always go somewhere_; if its only on the page to execute some javascript, then a `<button>` should be used instead. Using `<button>` is both more semantic, and spares you from this whole debate about what to hack into an anchor's `href`.  **Edit: looks like @Ronnie Royston's answer below already has this argument covered.**

Answer (score 16):

The `void` operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.
It avoids refreshing the page.

Answer (score 15):

From what I've seen, the [`void` operator](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/void) has 3 common uses in JavaScript. The one that you're referring to, `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` is a common trick to make an `<a>` tag a no-op. Some browsers treat `<a>` tags differently based on whether they have a `href` , so this is a way to create a link with a `href` that does nothing.

The `void` operator is a unary operator that takes an argument and returns `undefined`. So `var x = void 42;` means `x === undefined`. This is useful because, outside of [strict mode](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/strict), `undefined` is actually a valid variable name. So some JavaScript developers use `void 0` instead of `undefined`. In theory, you could also do `<a href="javascript:undefined">` and it would so the same thing as `void(0)`.