# How to open link (provided in youtube video) in external browser instead of app using javascript, or php

Tags: javascript, browser, external

How to open link (provided in youtube video) in external browser instead of app.

when i click on the link in description then a page opens in youtube app and shows the webpage but i want to display in external browsers, so what code i can do in my website to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

Use a target attribute in your anchor.

**target="_blank"** should do the trick.

```
<a target="_blank" href="daily-cat-video">click to see the cats</a>
```

If you want to get fancier and include window sizes and things, look at
[Opening new window in HTML for target="_blank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541392/opening-new-window-in-html-for-target-blank)
an  **window.open**.

. this will let you have more control over the window that gets open.

If you are in your mobile app, then opening in the youtube app is normal for android.  It looks at the intent and will present the user with the options that can handle that intent.
If it gets a youtube video, it will ask the user if they want to open it in youtube 'just once, or always' as well as give the user other apps that can handle the intent too, i.e chrome,