# Best practice for inserting large chunks of HTML into elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I'm building a web application (using prototype) that requires the addition of large chunks of HTML into the DOM.  Most of these are rows that contain elements with all manner of attributes.

Currently I keep a blank row of HTML in a variable and

```
var blankRow = '<tr><td>'
    +'<a href="{LINK}" onclick="someFunc(\'{STRING}\');">{WORD}</a>'
    +'</td></tr>';

function insertRow(o) {
    newRow = blankRow
        .sub('{LINK}',o.link)
        .sub('{STRING}',o.string)
        .sub('{WORD}',o.word);
    $('tbodyElem').insert( newRow );
}
```

Now that works all well and dandy, but is it the best practice?

I have to update the code in the blankRow when I update code on the page, so the new elements being inserted are the same.  It gets sucky when I have like 40 lines of HTML to go in a blankRow and then I have to escape it too.

Is there an easier way?  I was thinking of urlencoding and then decoding it before insertion but that would still mean a blankRow and lots of escaping.

What would be mean would be a eof function a la PHP et al.

```
$blankRow = <<<EOF
text
text
EOF;
```

That would mean no escaping but it would still need a blankRow.

What do you do in this situation?

## SOLVED

Ended up using a DOMBuilder in prototype.  No other libraries were needed:

```
$w('a div p span img table thead td th tr tbody tfoot input').each(function(e) {
        window['$' + e] = function() {
            return new Element(e, arguments[0]);
        }
});

newPart = $div({id: 'partition-4'})
    .insert( $p()
        .insert('<b>Stuff</b>')
    )
    .insert( $p({
        id: 'a-p'})
        .insert('<b>More stuff</b>')
    );

$('parentDiv').insert(newPart);
```

See my solution [here](http://pastebin.com/Du5Ejjjj) or [here](http://gist.github.com/402668).

Comment: Is your click function always a string?  It would be better if it were an actual function, but not sure if that's an option, also are you using jQuery? I can't be 100% sure from your syntax but it appears you are.

Comment: it isn't advisable to insert many nodes to the DOM one after the other. you should do it all at once. try inserting them to a container object first and then from the object to the DOM.

Comment: Nah the click function is just an example, mostly its numbers which cuts down the amount of escaping I need to do.  And yeah it's prototype, shoulda gone the jquery way but too late now.

Comment: Hey vsync would I create the container object first like container = document.createElement('tbody') throw all the tr's in there then do a $('actualTable').insert(container.childElements()) ?  Or .insert( container.innerHTML ) - [iirc insert wants a string arg...]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> is it the best practice?

No. In fact you've got HTML-injection problems leading to bugs, and in the worst case where the injected strings may contain user-submitted content, XSS security holes.

When you put plain text content and attribute values into an HTML string, you *must* HTML-encode them. In PHP, you have to call `htmlspecialchars()` on strings going into HTML to do it. In JavaScript, you don't get a built-in HTML-escaping function, so you have to make your own, eg. by using `s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')` on the string going into the HTML.

> onclick="someFunc(\'{STRING}\');"

That's a whole new level of escaping mess. In a JavaScript string literal inside an event handler attribute, you would have to JS-encode the string (`\`-escaping `'` and `\` plus a few Unicode characters for completeness) *and* then HTML-encode the results. Otherwise the string can break out of its string-literal delimiter and inject arbitrary JS code. Avoid inline event handler attributes in all cases, but especially in templating.

Creating page content with HTML strings sucks. You are very likely to make escaping errors and compromise the security of your application. Use DOM-like methods instead and you don't have to worry about this. You seem to be using jQuery, so try the jQuery 1.4 element creation shortcuts:

```
$('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').append(
        $('<a>', {
            href: o.link,
            text: o.word,
            onclick: function() {
                someFunc(o.string);
            }
        })
    )
);
```

or, keep your blank row actually inside the document as HTML, but then hide it (`display: none`) or detach it from the document at start time (`removeChild` or jQuery `detach`). Then when you want a new row, clone the blank row and make the changes you need:

```
var blankRow= $('#blankRow').detach();

    ...

var newRow= blankRow.clone();
var link= newRow.find('td>a');
link.attr('href': o.link);
link.text(o.word);
link.click(function() {
    someFunc(o.string);
});
```

If you must create content from string templates, ensure your templating function HTML-escapes every replacement by default, and attach events by selecting nodes inside the parsed content to call `click(function() { ... })` on. Or use event delegation (eg. jQuery `live()`) to handle events without having to bind to new nodes when added.

Comment: Man... what a mission.  Thanks for your help.  Really wish I was using jquery instead of prototype now :(

Comment: @hamstar: Oops! I should have spotted that was a Prototype ID selector `$` not jQuery. D'oh. Prototype has a similar (IMO: in some ways better) shortcut for creating elements, `new Element`. See http://prototypejs.org/2007/5/12/dom-builder

Comment: Sweet!  I might have to give that a go :) Cheers

Comment: Ended up doing it this way, worked awesomely!  Took a while to figure it out.  If anyone would like to see the code, see http://gist.github.com/402668 or http://pastebin.com/Du5Ejjjj
Thanks a lot for the info bobince!

Comment: I would strongly avoid setting event handler attributes from strings. I can't remember if Prototype works around the many IE bugs that would normally stop this working, but it's just pretty bad practice in any case; calling `.observe` as you do later on in the code is generally much better. Also `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` is an unpleasantness. Consider a clickable span or a button (styled to not look like a button if that's what you want). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean for discussion on this issue.

Comment: Best practice is actually using Document fragments for performance (they are stored in memory before being added to the dom) this is especially true for looped elements. Here is a post John Resig did on it http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: @bobince Brilliant response. After reading my first few books on web development, this one post did more to enlighten me on best practices than the lot combined.

Answer (score 5):

You do it using a good way, and that's pretty fast considering other manners.

An alternate, supposely clean solution is to build in javascript the DOM elements you are to use, by calling several

> document.createElement(tagName);

But your code will rapidly grow, in my thought, for nothing.

Another one, my favorite way to achieve DOM creation, is to place inside the HTML body the code you want to copy, give it a className and / or an id like "template" which will additionally ( using css ) hide it, and then process it as needed on event by getting the element back, cloning it, and setting property you want before appending where it belongs

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, your question is about initializing large strings the way you'll do that in PHP (or Perl for that matter)? For long (multiline) string I use:

```
var blankRow = [
     'a line',
     'another line',
     'still more lines',
     'lines lines lines',
     '... etc'
    ].join('')
```

You can also use a backslash for continuation, but that can get kind of messy:

```
var blankRow = 'a line\
another line\
still more lines\
lines lines lines\
... etc';
```

EDIT based on comment: I'm lazy too! So I use this for escaping:

```
function qs(str){
    str = str || this || '';
    return "'"+str+"'";
}

function qd(str){
    str = str || this || '';
    return '"'+str+'"';

}

String.prototype.qs = qs;
String.prototype.qd = qd;

// applied:
var blankRow = [
         'a line',
         'another '+qd('line'),
         'still more lines',
         'lines '+'lines'.qs()+ ' lines',
         '... etc'
        ].join('');
```

Problem with being lazy: it's pretty hard work to persist ones lazyness

Comment: Ahh thats a smart way to do it.  The reason I mentioned the PHP example is that you don't need to escape anything in the middle ;) <-- lazy