# Linking identical HTML over several pages

Tags: html, css

How would I link identical HTML used in several pages, instead of adding the same markup in all of the several pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an `iframe` on each of the several pages, with the `src` being the common HTML.

It also is possible on the client-side using javascript. jQuery makes this particularly easy providing a [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. You can use `jQuery.load()` to add an HTML block into elements across different HTML pages.

As an example, if every one of the pages has an `div` named `content`:

```
<div id=`contents`></div>
```

Then you could do this in each page:

```
$('#content').load('commonContent.html');
```

Comment: or wait no, the #content is loaded into the html

Comment: no, `commonContent` is the HTML that you want to share across **all** the pages. each of your _several pages_ that should contain identical markup would have a section named `content`, and the given code would load the same HTML into each of those pages

Comment: but what about the css? will it fall into line, or if not structured right probably be messed up..

Comment: generally the same CSS will apply to each of the several pages, but each page will need to include the relevant css, **or** you can similarly load that dynamically.

Comment: one possible objection to using an iframe is that it's deprecated in HTML/XHTML strict, but not in HTML5

Comment: the drawback of a javascript solution is that users can disable javascript, so it's often recommended to use javascript only to enhance a page but not to create essential content

Answer (score 3):

It can be done from the server side.

If you're using PHP, you can use `include()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using JavaScript http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/ht/htjsincludehtm.htm

Answer (score 1):

If it's allowed by the web host, server side includes (SSI) will do the trick. So, to insert the contents of a file "common.htm", just put this in the html for each page:

```
<!–-#include virtual="common.htm” -–>
```

you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Answer (score 1):

You should check: http://www.triadwebcrafters.com/article_server_side_language.cfm and [Best practice for inserting large chunks of HTML into elements with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839844/best-practice-for-inserting-large-chunks-of-html-into-elements-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into asp.net MVC framework. You have a Shared View in it to write the part which is common between different pages.