# what does javascript:void mean?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “javascript:void(0)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

In the below snippet what does `javascript:void` mean ? How can i make the user follow the link when he clicks the logout link provided `href="javascript:void"`?

```
<a href="javascript:void()" id="logout" onClick="#" ><strong>Logout</strong></a>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` is a function that takes any input and returns nothing.

It is commonly used in links to make them not go anywhere. Kind of like the links that have `href="#"`, but without affecting the browser history. There is almost always an `onclick` event attached that tells the browser what to actually do. In the code you gave, the onclick attribute is not valid JavaScript...

If you want the link to actually go somewhere, just use a regular `href`.

```
<a href="logout.php" id="logoug"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
```

Comment: can't i use `javascript:void` and then make the user go to some other link. Actually i don't wan't browser to let the user see the link he is about to click. Isn't it possible using onClick ?

Comment: I guess so: `<a href="javascript:void();" onClick="location.href='blah';">`, but why would you want to do that? The user will get to see it anyway when they click on it, and you're supposed to tell users what a link does...

Comment: It's an operator like `typeof`, not a function.  Parentheses are not required around its argument.

Comment: If you don't want the behaviour of an A element, don't use one. E.g. `<span onclick="document.location.href='whatever.com';">Foo</span>`.