# What is the purpose of this "javaScript:;"in hyperlink?

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of `javascript:;` in the *href* attributes of the hyperlinks?

```
<div data-trigger="spinner" id="spinner">
   <span id="spinner-value"></span>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" data-spin="spinner" data-rule="quantity" data-max="10">
   <a href="javascript:;" data-spin="down">-</a>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-spin="up">+</a>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW those should be buttons or even `<span>` tags; there's no point using an `<a>` if you're not really making a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the attribute `href="javascript:;"` is used to remove the behavior from the link.

If you would use eg. `href=""`, the webpage would reload when you click the link. But with `href="javascript:;"` nothing will happen.

Later a script adds an event handler that will be executed when clicking this link.

EDIT: You need `a` or `button` elements as they are the semantic representatives for clickable objects.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent links from refreshing webpage/redirecting you once clicked.

Answer (score 1):

the purpose of "javascript:;" have save meaning with "javascript:void(0)"

Read here : [javascript void functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037126/javascript-void-functions)