# What is the use of "javascript:void(0)"

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “javascript:void(0)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

I am checking many sites and I have seen that many website creator define inline JS function
"javascript:void(0)". I think this is a difining a JS function which does nothing.
example from images.google.com the image inside the search box contains.

```
<a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)">
         <span id="gs_si0">
             <span class="gssi_a gsst_e" id="qbi">
             </span>
         </span>
</a>
```

Can anybody explain what is the use of benifit of defining this function even this function does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers don't render `a` contents styled like a link (blue underline, hand cursor, etc) unless there's a `href` attribute present, and if this "no-op" `href` later gets supplanted by an `onclick` handler attached to the element, then that's why you might use it.