# Usecases for javascript's void function aside from undefined

Tags: javascript, void

Aside from the obvious preventing of links being clicked (with `javascript:void(0);`) and for the definition of `undefined` in many javascript precompiled languages like coffeescript (where `undefined` becomes `void 0`) --> What else can the `void` function be used for?

---

Related: [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Useful Link: [MDN page for `void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

Comment: +1 Why was this downvoted? How is this not constructive?

Comment: Haha I have no idea @JosephSilber some people just vote and dodge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `void` is an operator, not a function.  The answer to your question can't be given any more clearly than the explanation given in the [link to MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean) you provided in your question:

> ### Summary
>
> The `void` operator evaluates the given expression and then returns `undefined`.
>
> ...
>
> ### Uses
>
> This operator allows inserting expressions that produce side effects into places where an expression that evaluates to `undefined` is desired.

#### Theoretical use:

Change the return value of an expression that produces side effects.

```
var i;
i = 0;       // returns 0
void i = 1;  // returns undefined
```

But this use is not very valuable in most situations.

#### Practical uses:

We already know about:

- Cancel navigation in a bookmarklet
- Compare item to `undefined` - Since the global variable `undefined` could be modified (it is not a reserved word), `void 0` is a more reliable way to get an `undefined` value.  Eg: `obj.foo === void 0`

Other uses:

**Prevent verbose console output** - I use it in a JavaScript console when I only want to execute some code and don't want to pollute the console with uninteresting verbose output.

**Explicitly pass `undefined` to a function** - It can be useful to know whether a function was called without passing arguments, or whether an argument was passed to a function with a value of `undefined`:

```
function countArguments(a) {
    console.log(a === undefined);
    console.log(arguments.length);
}
countArguments();
countArguments(void 0);
```

Your console output would be:

```
true
0
true
1
```

Does JavaScript *need* this operator?  Probably not.  You can get the same functionality (and more) from a self invoking anonymous function:

```
(function(){ /* expression */ })()
```

But that's not quite as concise.

Comment: yea. so what does `void 1...n` do? or is it only `void 0` that does anything?

Comment: No, because the expressions `0`, `1`, or `n` produce no side effects - those expressions don't do anything.  `void 0` is essentially identical to `void 1` because there is no side effect and the return value is `undefined`.

Comment: So why does `void` even need an argument?

Comment: Because it is an operator.  An operator must *operate* on some expression.  If it were a function, it would not necessarily need an expression.

Comment: Operators need no expressions! **Y U LIE** take `break;` or `continue;` for example

Comment: @Neal `break` and `continue` are statements. Most operators are unary or binary, I never heard of nullary operators.

Comment: Still does not answer my question of why it **always** returns `undefined`.... where is the point in that?

Comment: @Neal I think the reason is "the global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value)." (see MDN). You cant be sure that `undefined` is really _undefined_.

Comment: The reason it always returns `undefined` is because [that's how the spec defines it](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.2).  It sounds like you want to know why it exists.  I don't know... convenience? Surely there are other ways to get the functionality it provides.  Maybe one of the authors of ECMAScript-262 will come along and provide some insight.

Comment: "Since the global variable undefined could be modified (it is not a reserved word), void 0 is a more reliable way to get an undefined value" +1