# Use of Javascript:void(0) v/s #

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Method1()">Link 1</a>
```

I realize that the above method of using `javascript:void(0)` is a bad practice and a better way of handling undefined would be

```
<a href="#" onclick="Method1()">Link 1</a>
```

My question is:

Is there ever a situation where we should be using `javascript:void(0)` as against `<a href="#">`

Comment: there is good deal of discussion already on SO here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean  and even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javascript:void(0)` is superior to `#` since it doesn't claim that a suitable fallback (for when the JavaScript fails for any reason) is to scroll back to the top of the page.

Neither are good though, JavaScript should be implemented [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [progressively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Comment: So in that case the best way to handle a javascript failure would be javascript:void(0)  ?

Comment: No. The best way is with a real link that goes somewhere sensible (such as something that does the same operation server side).