# Why use href="javascript:void()?

Tags: javascript

Reading this question : [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean) I can understand why `<a href="javascript:void(0)"` is used - in order to prevent a page redirection.

I have come across this code :

```
<a id="myId" href="javascript:void()"
    onclick="removePopup()">Close</a>
```

The operator `void` does not take any parameter in this case. Is this a bug ?

Comment: Both are same.  No Difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug. The browser will throw a syntax error when the link is clicked, unless the `removePopup()` function stops the default action. (If the function *does* that, it might explain why the developer didn't notice it.)

```
> void()
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```