# Navbar behaving oddly, and so is footer, on Mobile [front end]

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom

So I have this heroku app... that is behaving oddly on mobile. [ namely chrome on iPhone, and few others ]

The first is that on my iPhone, when I click the login page, the footer gets pushed up to the middle of the page, and I am wondering why that is and how to get rid of that. [again on iPhone, on Chrome] I thought

```
bottom: 0px;
```

would fix it.

The second is that the navbar will close after opening it, sometimes, again I am not exactly sure why that is happening. Again I am a little perplexed.

Any help would be amazing!

Edit : I think I have solved problem one but I am not sure how to test it. All I did was add data-hide-during-focus="" to the footer.

Any ideas on how to test locally?

Edit 2: I found a nice way of testing locally called User Agent Switcher for firefox, but I still have the bugs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the menu from closing on click in iOS, try replacing `<a href="/" class="navbar-brand"></a>` with `<a href="javascript: void(0)" class="navbar-brand"></a>`

Comment: Can you explain why this fixed it, please?

Comment: Sure, when you use a '/' in a link, it goes to the document root, so you were effectively refreshing the page when the mobile nav was clicked.
Check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a Mac? You can test with an iPhone on a Mac by downloading XCode and using the IOS simulator.

Comment: Thank you! I am not though, I realized that I can connect to the port on my iPhone. I am within a virtual box, currently trying to figure that out. So far so bad. =/

Comment: Try using Chrome and swapping to "Inspect Element", Setting wheel (bottom right) and Settings -> Overrides on the left. You can swap your User Agent to IOS. I've had *some* luck with that.