# What is "void 0"?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript by reading some code, but this function really puzzles me.

```
    hv:
        function(i) {
            var _this = this;
            return isArr(_this) ? _this.indexOf(i) > -1 : _this[i] !== void 0;
        }
```

This function is added to `Object.prototype`.
I don't quite get the `void 0` at the end of the ternary expression. Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this code from?

Comment: See the answer here [void 0 stackoverflorw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Comment: @kojiro https://github.com/foray1010/Popup-my-Bookmarks/blob/master/js/common.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined primitive value, 
>       usually using “void(0)” (which is equivalent to “void 0”). In these cases, the 
>       global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned 
>       to a non-default value).

in this cases, the global variable [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) can be used instead:
ie:

```
_this[i] !== undefined;
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2XkR4/3/)

Comment: its been answered already by a link

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: Its a duplicate question

Comment: Thanks, actually I found void(0) while googling but I thought it'd be different from void 0.

Comment: @alexmac i actually googled it. so `undefined` can also be used??

Comment: No idea, I saw that it is a duplicate question is all.  never used it, why use code like that, when it confuses the programmers :)

Comment: @alexmac for example: `var x;
if (x === undefined) alert('novalue');
else alert(x);` [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2XkR4/1)

Comment: @suhail MDN says `undefined` can be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

`void 0` is a way of getting `undefined` without fail. Some browsers allow overriding the `undefined` variable, but you can't override `void`