# What is the meaining of void in javascript and its usage in jshint?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading jshint source code and found `return void error("E009");` line.

I know `void` means return nothing in languages such as `C` and `C++`. But what does it mean in javascript and how can it be used? Or is it good practice to use it in Javascript?

Comment: you can also check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Comment: Both the linked answers show usage in links, where you don't want the page to change. This usage is similar but different. Compared to "error(x); return void 0;" it saves on 1 line and the braces on the conditional. Compared to "return error(x);" it saves you having to read the code for error() and figuring out that it returns undefined - which, in fact, it does. Neither of these advantages add up to much, it just seems to be this coder's style (he calls the commit just a 'minor refactoring' https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/bb04a20796f50ba30498c947f4f9271a03362bde)