# Anchor tag get added to the tab in IE

Tags: jquery, html

I have simple links

```
<a id="link0" href="#" value="2esndyhczh"><i class="icon-video"></i> Getting started</a>
<a id="link1" href="#" value="hi3ykdw15k"><i class="icon-video"></i> Library search</a>
<a id="link2" href="#" value="a4nr018bji"><i class="icon-video"></i> Browse</a>
<a id="link3" href="#" value="75dp08bgqx"><i class="icon-video"></i> Title details</a>
<a id="link4" href="#" value="xuwbktofcr"><i class="icon-video"></i> Borrow</a>
```

these links change the video inside the Wistia player. The problem is that in IE `#` gets added in the tab any time I click the links.
I use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent link to anchor.

After couple of clicks I get `##########` in IE tab.

Comment: You can use `href="javascript:void(0)"`. However its not good practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Comment: this is still adding the parent anchor which is the tab page

Comment: is the parent anchor in the code above? think im not seeing it

Comment: well, the parent anchor is tab. I use three tabs, this is the video tab...not to be confused with the IE tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou can use `href="javascript:void(0)"`