# Stop Angular routing links inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using Angular JS to dynamically load content like so:

**HTML**

```
  ...

  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

</html>
```

**Angular**

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/test', {
      templateUrl : 'views/test.html',
      controller  : 'MainController'
    });

  });

  app.controller('MainController', function($scope){ });

})();
```

This works as expected. However, inside the file test.html I have some links with the `href="#"` that need to be handled with javascript to do various things. At the moment, Angular is interpreting them with it's routing method and treats them as links to the homepage. How do I stop this and treat the links the way I want?

Example test.html content:

```
<a href="#" class="slideLeft">Left</a>
<a href="#" class="slideRight">Right</a>
<p>Test content</p>
```

In a JS file separate from Angular I tried:

```
$('.slideLeft').on('click',function(){
  return false;
});
```

But it doesn't do the return false, it uses the Angular routing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1291950/1059101 this could help you.

Comment: You're using jQuery for something that should be handled by Angular. Use an ng-click attribute instead, or better yet, write a slider directive.

Comment: You want to disable the routing behavior for the entire app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Angular for all your bindings including event bindings.  Don't use `.on('click')`, use `ng-click` (or `.bind` if you really need it, but you probably don't).

You can also see from the docs that the [`<a>` directive does nothing if `href` is empty](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ng/directive/a).  Use `href=""` rather than `href="#"`

Comment: Ah very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `href="javascript:void(0)"` in anchor attribute and also you should use `ngClick` instead of binding element using jQuery.