# Use <a> tags or any tags for javascript links?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

Is there a preferred way or advantages to using one over the other ?

i.e.

1. You can have a hyperlink `a` where the `href` points to `#` with a `class` or `id` and then javascript that looks for that elements `on-click` event.
2. You can have a simple div or span that has a `class` or `id` and bind the javascript `on-click` to that element.

I have seen both done.

Context is ruby on rails applications that are using javascript for some functionality.

Comment: Remember to `return false` onclick if you do not want to follow the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean/1291950#1291950

Comment: Is that similar to `preventDefault()` (or the newer `defaultPrevented`) ?

Comment: A elements with hrefs are automatically added to the [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links) collection, scripted links aren't.

Comment: defaultPrevented tells you if preventDefault is active on the object. preventDefault() is similar to return false. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @RobG - what kinds of links do you mean? This one works http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xmsh0aaa/

Comment: @mplungjan—scripted "links" like `<span onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com'">Google</span>` are not included in *document.links*.

Comment: Ah, true. Not sure what you meant. "Scripted spans"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an HTML question than javascript.

1. A elements are simple, work in every browser and are utterly reliable whether scripting is available or not.
2. Browsers support A elements through context menu features to open them in new windows or tabs
3. A elements have a default presentation in browsers that lets users know they are links without any other scripting or styling support required
4. Different browsers may present links slightly differently, so users get used to seeing them behave in the particular way their browser presents them. Scripted and styled other elements likely will present in an unfamiliar way to at least some users.
5. Browsers offer features to support A element links such as tab navigation between links and separate lists of links in the page.
6. Screen readers and other support mechanisms for accessibility understand A element links and can present them to their users
7. Browsers typically present the destination of an A element link to a user so they can decide whether to follow the link or not
8. A element URLs are easily copied and shared without following the link
9. A elements can be used to create bookmarks without following the link

Scripted and styled links do not have any of the above features, or at least require significant additional effort to support any of them.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main advantage of using `<a>` tags is that the default behavior (when including an `href`) is that the browser cursor signifies an link. Although both can be done, using the `<a>` tag is also more semantic.

Comment: +1 Thanks.  I wonder if it varies according to the sort of functionality being done.  Maybe there are cases where the rollover and the (e.g.) hand symbol obscures content.  Though I can't think of a specific example right now.  When appropriate though a tags might have(?) the big advantage of alt text and title for rollovers and screen readers ?

Answer (score 2):

Constructing semantic markup is a staple of good design.  By using anchors to signify navigation, you are sticking to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).  The perfered way would be what the spec outlines, if you need to deviate I would make sure your changes are justified.

**One advantage** for preferring an anchor tag is screen reader software for the blind will parse the DOM for anchors to help users navigate on the page.  By using div's or span's the nav links will be overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I like to write code which actually means something. I generally achieve this by using the most appropriate (semantically speaking) elements.

- I use the `a` element when the purpose is to navigate in the application. To quote the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#links):

> Links are a conceptual construct [...] that represent a connection between two resources

- For other cases, it depends. But I usually use the `button` element
- `div` are by definition meaningless, you should avoid them for this kind of purpose. To quote the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element):

> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a JavaScript-only link then it doesn't matter what element you attach it but using an `<a>` gives you built-in link/hover/visited styles whilst being semantically correct. However, the biggest reason for using an actual link is the ability to have a fall-back for browsers without JS enabled.

For example, you could have a link which loaded the next 10 results by ajax  if possible else server-side if the link is followed.

```
<a id="nextByAjax" href="?next=10">Next 10</a>
```