# How do I link_to a javascript:void in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying this with no luck:

```
{{ link_to('javascript:void;', 'Print', array('onClick' => 'iPrint(docIframe)', 'style' => 'float:right; position:relative; top:-410px;')) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the `link_to` function prepends the site root to `javascript:void`. You could work around this by adding `#` in front of `javascript:void`, causing the `link_to` function to treat your link as a valid URL so that it doesn't need to add the site root:

```
{{ link_to('#javascript:void;', 'Print', array('onClick' => 'iPrint(docIframe)', 'style' => 'float:right; position:relative; top:-410px;')) }}
```

This will successfully execute the javascript and trigger `onClick`, though note it will also show the `#` link in the browser's location box.

In a case like this, it would be better perhaps to skip Blade altogether and just use `<a href...>`.

It should also be mentioned that using `javascript:void(0)` is not always the best idea; see the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293130/4043861.