# javascript onclick function doesn't work with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html

If I try to pass a parameter to a function in the `onclick` event it doesn't work, `clase` is to access to clase/index method from a codeigniter controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url('js/action.js');?>"></script>

    </head>
    <body>   
        <div class='container'>
            <h1>Esta página es solo accesible para el administrador.</h1>
             <a class="btn btn-success" onclick ="go('clase')">Volver</a>'
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the function

```
function go(url){
    //var url = "clase";    
    $(location).attr('href',url);
}
```

Without the parameter it works. But if I pass the parameter, nothing happens.

Comment: where you are passing the parameters ?

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-success" onclick ="go('clase')">Volver</a>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go(url){  
    $(location).attr('href',url);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" onclick="go('clase')">Volver</a>
```

- Add `href="javascript:void(0);"`, see: [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)
- Remove the `'` after the `</a>`-tag.

Answer (score 2):

remove last `comma` from your anchor tag and add `href` to anchor tag

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick ="go('clase')">Volver</a>
```

and make sure your `go()` inside `script` tag