# Why does the page go blank when injecting JavaScript code via the address bar?

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-injection

So if I want to make a change, for example in this page (stackoverflow.com), using:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("hlogo").innerHTML = "10";
```

The page goes blank, only showing the string "10", even though the source code is still there.

Yet if I do this in an HTML document internally via the JavaScript console it doesn't remove the rest of the content visually.

Comment: I dont follow the question?

Comment: so what's the trouble? where are you doing this javascript callout??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append a `void(0)` or any expression returning an undefined value:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("hlogo").innerHTML = "10";void(0);
```

This answer explains this behavior well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291950/689788