# Bootstrap collapse brokes with image as header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, toggle

I use bootstrap 3.3.6, ui-bootstrap 1.2.2 and I try to use `collapse`. 
The header has to be an image. This is my code

```
 <div id="isOpen"  > 
    <img data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#readThis" src="./images/hello.jpg" /> 
    <div id="readThis" > Get more info</div>

 </div>
```

The `readThis` `div` appears opened and when I click the image to close it, it starts to close, and then re-opens.

After that works fine.

How do I fix this? Is there another bootstarp module that will work with images? I try to fix this all day, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try by putting `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#readThis"` on `<a>` tag and put image inside it

```
<a href="#readThis" data-toggle="collapse">
   <img src="./images/hello.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: yes, but, since this is a single-page application, when I hit that `<a>` it tries to go to the `#readThis` page, and it redirects to nowhere. Any tips?

Comment: yeah do <a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-target="#readThis" data-toggle="collapse">

Comment: use javascript:; or javascript:void(0) inside href see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Comment: Looks really good, I will fix m page and test it and let you know. Thanks