# Clicking on an empty anchor link sends the user to the top of the page

Tags: javascript

I have two empty anchor links `<a href="#">` that are used to create tabs. Please take a look at my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/cuuy5cbp/

The problem is that the user goes to the very top of the page when going from tab to tab. I would use jQuery-UI's tabs, but I have the same HTML element for each tab, and think jQuery-UI's tabs force you to have different HTML elements in each tab.

I want to use these tabs further down my page, and making the user scroll down after every tab switch is not user-friendly. How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:** If I click on "Tab 1" to activate it, I shouldn't be able to hit the Tab key on my keyboard and Tab 2 is now highlighted.

Comment: You can fix this in the jquery functions as well.. but you haven't included any jquery in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `href="#/"`. It should prevent this behavior from happening.

Comment: I'd like to know that too

Comment: It prevents the behavior from happening, but is a hack conceptually identical to using `href="#anyIDThatDoestExistOnThePage"`. A better approach would be to _prevent_ the anchor tag from trying to act as a hyperlink in the first place, rather than turning it into an _explicitly broken_ hyperlink

Comment: @Hamms `/` is not a valid ID character so I don't think it's the *same* as like you described `href="#anyIDThatDoestExistOnThePage"` but rather a nice URI hack.

Comment: Well I'm curious to see in what using `href="javascript:void(0)"` is "less hacky" than this answer, since `void(0)` evaluates to undefined, so to me they're kind of equivalent. Actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`.

https://jsfiddle.net/obybyvds/

Here's an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291950/515502) of why that works

Comment: or just `<a>`. In HTML5, anchor tags without attributes are valid.

Comment: That's true but then the cursor doesn't change like anchor tags with a href.

Comment: Why not simply `javascript:;`

Comment: a simple `cursor: pointer;` CSS rule will make the cursor change. I encourage you to read [the explanation right below the one you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1293130/1810460)

Comment: That also works! `void(0)` is just a bit more explicit, and easier to read (in the sense that it might be hard to notice the `;`)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `href` to `javascript:;`

```
<a href="javascript:;">Tab 1</a>
```

**Or** keep the `href="#"` and simply `event.preventDefault()` on click using this **JavaScript**:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[href='#']"), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
});
```

<sup>[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cuuy5cbp/5/)</sup>

or in **jQuery**:

```
$(document).on("click", "[href='#']", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```