# convert bad <span href="#"> to correct <a href="#">

Tags: css

This code gives errors in the W3 Validator, however it does the job on click.

```
<span href="#" class="click">+</span>
```

If I convert it to the code below it validates in the W3 but on click the pointer moves up, on the screen. It does not stay on the "+"

```
<a href="#" class="click">+</a>
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Can you share a JS Fiddle showing your problem? Or a code snippet?

Comment: Why do you even care about W3C validation? Think about **that**

Comment: Why should I not care about W3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid click jumps on anchor tags, remove hash and add `javascript:;` instead, like below:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="click">+</a>
```

Comment: why messing around with inline js? just use a `<button>` element instead. so you don't have to abuse the `<a>`

Comment: I have suggested the answer as per the question, OP was facing click jumps problem, so I just suggested him that, changing the tag is his decision.

Comment: sure, but the "click jump problem" is the result of using the wrong tag for this case :)

Answer (score 3):

please use a `<button>` instead of `<a>` if you don't want to provide a link!

a `<button>` element is exactly what you want, because the `<a>` tag is for links and a `href="#"` would trigger a jump to top.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this way.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"; class="click">+</a>
```

you refer more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)