# Rotate only this div.. not others

Tags: jquery

Want to rotate div 45 degree on each click. It works fine as expected. I have 3 '.expand-btn' class name in this page. What happens, on click it triggers on all '.expand-btn'.

I want to trigger only on this 'expand-btn'. not others.

**JS:**

```
var _rotation = 0;

$.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$('.expand-btn').click(function() {
    _rotation += 45;
    $(this).rotate(_rotation);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="expand-btn" id="test1">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse">+</a>
</div>
<div class="expand-btn" id="test2">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse">+</a>
</div>
<div class="expand-btn" id="test3">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse">+</a>
</div>
```

Comment: should work because of this context..

Comment: It doesn't work because a single `_rotation` variable is being used for all 3..

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0)"` is a very old and very [bad anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293130/778975). The `javascript:` pseudo-URLs were [intended for creating bookmarklets](http://javascriptexample.net/badjs01.php) and shouldn't be used in page scripting. You might benefit from reading a blog post I wrote recently about [spotting bad JS tutorials](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have a distinct storage of the rotation value for each of the objects. You could e.g. use [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for that:

```
$.fn.rotate = function(delta) {
   // get the current stored rotation, or 0 if none was currently stored
   var degrees = $(this).data().rotation || 0;

   // add the delta to this value
   degrees += delta;

   // store the new value with the object
   $(this).data().rotation = degrees;

   // set the transformation
   $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$('.expand-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).rotate(45);
});
```

To extend a jQuery set correctly you should iterate over the elements of the set and apply the code for each of the individually. The way `$.fn.rotate` is written now will set the rotation of all elements in the set based on the value of the first one.

Or parse the current `transform` to retrieve that actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data- attribute to the div where you can store the current angle.

HTML:

```
<div class="expand-btn" id="test1" data-degrees="0">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse">+</a>
</div>
<div class="expand-btn" id="test2" data-degrees="0">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse">+</a>
</div>
<div class="expand-btn" id="test3" data-degrees="0">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="collapse">+</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.expand-btn').click(function() {
        var currentDegrees = $(this).data("degrees");
      currentDegrees += 15;
      $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate(' + currentDegrees + 'deg)'});
      var currentDegrees = $(this).data("degrees", currentDegrees);
  });
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tejsoft/dwxb1a1b/