# HTML href="#" in php

Tags: php, html, href

In HTML you can write href="#" to prevent a page reload, however in php this doesn't appear to work. Is there an alternative?

It adds # to the existing url, but that's not what I want. I also don't want to remove the href since it replaces the cursor with a select text cursor, and I don't really want to be changing my css for what should be basic php.

I'm sure im just doing something wrong anyway. Thanks!

Comment: ok i didnt realise this, my html seems to be adding # to the url with href="#" too. What can you do to stop it from this? or is this normal behaviour?

Comment: write href="javascript:;" instead of #

Comment: `replaces the cursor with a select text cursor` can be fixed with a CSS rule. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: @SubhashShipu is this really the best way of doing this? it works, but it's not clean.

Comment: @chris85 yeah I know cursor: pointer works, but i already said i don't want any css to get involved with this. The css is common across every page, so i'd have to do it inline. empty href's are also invalid html for <a> elements.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I want to prevent the links in my header from working on the page that is currently open. If I leave the home link href="home.html" it reloads the page, and href="#" changes the url. Also causes the page to jump to the top.

Comment: @JoshLyness check my answer below

Comment: @JoshLyness `href` is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a hash you're attempting to tell the browser to navigate to an anchor on the page.  If you want to cancel the default behavior and not modify your CSS simply void the anchor's behavior with Javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">...</a>
```

There's a very good description of what this does and why you would use it here: [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Comment: it works, but it's not great. It's hacky.

Comment: i won't argue with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not be the best. But if I had this issue, I'll use `onclick`

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false"> texts</a>
```

[Online Preview](http://fiddlesalad.com/html/on-click-event)

Comment: doesn't behave any differently to href="#" by itself? That only effects javascript events?

Comment: when you click on it nothing happens

Comment: nothing happens with href="#", with or without onclick="return false" it adds # to the url and scrolls the page to the top

Comment: no way. it won't react at all. Tested.

Comment: @JoshLyness check this preview http://fiddlesalad.com/html/on-click-event

Comment: well i added it to a site im working on and it doesnt work. maybe if you have a href="#" it doesnt work?

Comment: check above link n see

Comment: it doesn't really matter if a fiddle works if, when i test it, it doesn't