# Target a CSS modal to open without href

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created this modal pop up using CSS and `href` to target the modal to open on click. This seems to work in demos, but once I tried to use on my app, every time I click on the modal to open, it changes the URL with the modal ID and refreshes the page, which shouldn't happen.

```
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <a class="fullSizeBlock" href="#close"></a>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#close">X</a>
      <h1>Modal Box</h1>
      <button ng-click="changeState()">Show Client</button>
      <div ng-if="client.state">{{client.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`#openModal` goes into the URL and page auto refreshes. How can I avoid this?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MBp5OnV1QR1sCaytCYBV?p=preview)

Comment: You may looking for javascript.void(0). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Comment: Nothing “refreshes” when I open that modal in your plunkr, at least not in my browser. // You should really rather be using JS for this - _accessibility_ of those CSS-only “solutions” is usually rather terrible. JS allows you to toggle the proper ARIA attributes etc.

Comment: So get rid of the href approach and use your controller data model to manage the modal state instead. You might consider creating a modal service for this

Comment: @CBroe yes, but its having a different effect on my app. changes the URL according to the div class or id and it reloads the page with that new URL

Comment: Well then you should try to create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `preventDefault()` function. I'll use `open-modal-anchor` as a class for demo purposes.

```
$('.open-modal-anchor').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. still reloading the page because its changing the url