# Preventing Specific Anchors from Adding Irrelevant Entries to Browser History?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, browser-history

Is it possible to prevent selected anchors from adding to the browser's history?

For a site I am working on now, this is a particular issue when I try to prompt back to a previous page. By doing so the anchors repeat in the order they where activated, and I have to click back more than once before returning back to the previous page.

Here's some code I am currently working with. Is there a function I can implement to achieve this result?

```
<!-- Image with Anchor to Open Lightbox Window -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://URLTOPIC.jpg">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Prompt with Anchor to Close Window -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `<a>` is not a good element to use for pure JS functionality. Use a `<button>` instead.

Comment: @connexo So you're saying I should use a `<button>` tag with the anchor, instead of an `<a>` tag? Doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: `<a>` is meant to be used for one of two purposes: To navigate to a new page, or to jump to an anchor within the same page. For all else, use different elements.

Comment: Ok, then can I activate these anchors within the page with different elements then? I'm just trying to have them function without adding to the browser's history.

Comment: Could I use something like `<a href="javascript:;">` and still have the anchor function?

Answer (score 0):

When using a empty anchor, for example `<a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>` which is used as a button, you can set the href this way that will disable the anchor events `<a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="javaScript:void(0);"></a>`

You can read more about the javascript URI scheme [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

For the links you are using to trigger the models, avoid the default behavior for it to be added to the window.history object

```
document.querySelector('.trigger').addEventLister('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //Do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Ok. So, in the example I've provided, the `.trigger` would be `.lb-animate`? What about `<a href="#view">`?

Comment: Sorry, just a bit confused...

Comment: No, .trigger is a class you use to show the modal.

therefore <a href="#view" class="trigger-modal">

Then you add a event listener to that document.querySelector('.trigger')addEventLister('click', showModal);

And inside the JS function that shows the modal you will pass it the event as a parameter and then avoid the usual behavior 

function showModal(e){e.preventDefault()}

Comment: Why would he even use an `a` element for this? With a `button type=button` the step of disabling default behaviour isn't even necessary. `a` is obviously an inappropriate element for the job.

Comment: @connexo how can I use ```button type=button``` without JS to link to an anchor and not alter the browser history?