# [routerLink]="" VS href="javascript:void(0);"

Tags: javascript, angular, anchor

If I want to add a dead link to an anchor tag because I want to use (click) instead then I can use either `[routerLink]=""` or `href="javascript:void(0);"`. Both has the same effect and I see no difference in browser compatibility.

Which one is prefered to use? Is there any difference?

Comment: If it's a deadlink on which you bind `click` event, you don't need both.

Comment: I weren't using both - just one or the other. The question states which would be prefered to use.

Comment: What i'm saying is that none is needed. ;)

Comment: So you mean "you don't need any" then? ;) But I agree - unless you want the styling for an anchor which is only added if you add the href or routerLink attribute to the tag. I know you can just create your own stylings but keeping the default styling just by adding one of the attributes makes perfect sense to me. :)

Comment: This is what i mean. But making styling based on `href` attribute (or routerLink) is a bad practice. One should use `class` attribute or other kind of selector. ;)

Comment: So you suggest not to add href or routerLink, manually duplicating the default link styling af an anchor and add it as a class to every anchor tag?

Comment: Exactly. It will not cause side effects like with adding `href` or `routerLink`. It will require to redefine default link style but, imho, it's simpler to deal with css than trying to compensate side effects with these attributes in Angular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[routerLink]=""
```

What this line does it, It will redirect to your home route/root route, whereas

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

> The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.

for more information read out here -

[* What does “javascript:void(0)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Apart from this if you want to make it `a` as deadlink just pass event through the click event and use `event.preventDefault()` which will stop default action of anchor tag will execute what you want to do.