# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input js

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I Have this code where i keep getting the same error after trying everything. I have also checked other similar stackoverflow question but still no answer worked please can you help me out

**ERROR:** *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input*

**Javascript**

```
const colors = document.getElementsByClassName('s-colors');

for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {

    colors[i].addEventListener('click', () => {

            console.log(this.getAttribute("data-color"));

    })

}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="pdt-color">
    <h4>Color</h4>
    <div class="colors">
        <a href="javascript:void" class="s-colors" data-color="red"
            style="background-color: red;"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void" class="s-colors" data-color="black"
            style="background-color: black;"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void" class="s-colors" data-color="yellow"
            style="background-color: yellow;"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void" class="s-colors" data-color="blue"
            style="background-color: blue;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add running snippet of code.

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: this code not giving any issue. add your css also in snippet

Comment: @Cid both chrome and firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
```

javascript:void is an incomplete statement, that's why you run into problems here.

Comment: `void` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: that's true, but still: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean - you could write "void 0" as well.

Answer (score 3):

The code below should do the trick. I replaced the javascript links with # links and prevent the URL from changing on click by using the preventDefault function. Give it a try.

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.s-colors');

colors.forEach(color => {
    color.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(color.dataset.color);
    });
});
```

```css
.s-colors {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h4>Color</h4>
<a href="#" class="s-colors" data-color="red" style="background-color: red;"></a>
<a href="#" class="s-colors" data-color="black" style="background-color: black;"></a>
<a href="#" class="s-colors" data-color="yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></a>
<a href="#" class="s-colors" data-color="blue" style="background-color: blue;"></a>
```