# Javascript:Void(0); Vs Javascript:;

Tags: javascript

I recently saw `href='javascript:;'`. What's the difference between:

```
<a href='javascript:;'
```

vs:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'
```

When to use first one, and when to use second?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Comment: @KamuranSönecek i know what `javascript:void(0)` means. i'm asking about how it's different from  `javascript:;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is a JavaScript program with no statements which resolves as undefined, the other uses `void` to explicitly resolve as undefined. There is little to choose between them.

**Never use either**.

Only use a link if you are going to link to somewhere.

If you want a UI control that people can click on to trigger some JavaScript, use a `<button type="button">`.

Comment: I once had a heated debate with a designer about the semantic differences between buttons and links. - (cool story bro)

Comment: @Quentin Is there any special reason for not using it? (sometimes using an <a> tag is easier to style and it's more semantical. for example currently i'm reading a code that has this <a> tag in <nav>, and it overrides the links behavior with `javascript:void(0)` to navigate manually with code. )

Comment: @yaya — The purpose of a link is to link somewhere. The semantics of it are explicitly about linking somewhere. If you aren't linking then the semantics are wrong.

Comment: @Quentin yeah but isn't it better to put some <a> tags in <nav> ? cause `<nav><button></button></nav>` sounds abit odd... doesn't search engines expect such tags? (links inside of nav)

Comment: @yaya — No, it absolutely is not. You might find a button inside a navigation section to be odd, but it is much less odd than a link which doesn't link anywhere. Search engines definitely do not expect to have a link which doesn't link anywhere.

Comment: @Quentin thanks. maybe we just got used to it because we see it a lot in codes. but i agree, semantically we're better to use buttons.

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical difference. Both result in the expression evaluating to `undefined`.

`void` / `void()` is just a shortcut to get to `undefined`, as is an empty expression terminating with an immediate semicolon.