# preventDefault() click event for links what I want to stop to reload page not all links

Tags: javascript, dom-events, preventdefault

```
 const preventReloadLinks = container.querySelectorAll('.leftnav-link');
  preventReloadLinks.forEach(link => {
   addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault()
    });
   })
```

Hi Everyone I'm using this piece of code to stop links in the nav causing page reload, it works but unfortunately it stoped (prevented) from click other links on my page to external pages which I want them to work.I tried more specific selector but it the same. How can I stop this behavior or reverse it for the other links. thanks

Comment: Use `href="javascript:void(0)"`. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code adds an eventListener to the window for each link in nav.

```
addEventListener('click', function (e) { // same as window.addEventListener
   e.preventDefault()
});
```

So you missed `link.` and the code should be

```
link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
});
```

But I suggest instead to delegate, then you do not have to loop

```js
container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("a"); // or just e.target if there are no child elements in the link 
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("leftnav-link")) { 
     e.preventDefault()
  }   
})
```

Comment: thank you very much the missed link. sorted everything      
 preventReloadLinks.forEach(link => {
 link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault()
 });

Answer (score 0):

```js
const preventReloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.leftnav-link');
for (let i = 0; i < preventReloadLinks.length; i++) {
    preventReloadLinks[i].onclick = () => false;
}
```

Comment: No need to change the forEach to a for loop. The mistake was to keep adding eventlistener to window as [I have detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67333534/295783)

Answer (score -1):

Add another custom class to the links which are created by you which must be absent in foreign links.

Then modify the querySelector() for custom class