# Best Way to give keyboard focus for a icon

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have a ChevronUp/down icon which serves as a button to open/close the menu.

[image]

I want to give keyboard focus to the icon for accessibility support.
I tried to add it into "a" tag
`<a href="#"> <i></i> </a>`

It gives focus but when it's clicked, the href="#" part will make the page refresh. I am wondering what's the best way to give keyboard focus for  tag?

I tried "return false" for the `<a>` tag, but it also doesn't work as it will disable the all onclick events.

Comment: Why exactly the icon should be focusable?

Comment: If it is a button use a `<button>` not a link

Comment: @KonradLinkowski 
We want users to be able to click it through keyboard.

Comment: _I tried "return false" for the <a> tag_, where did you return false, inside the href attribute? try `<a href="#" onclick="return false;"><i></i></a>`

Comment: If you insist to use an `<a>` tag, you may try `<a href="javascript: void(0)">...</a>`, a [common way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean) to get rid of the default behaviour of an `<a>` tag.

Comment: @kevinzf — What makes you think users *can't* 'click' a button using the keyboard?

Comment: Also, if you care about accessibility you need to let people who can't see (what I assume is) *a background image on your italic non-text* know what the button does. Use an `<img>` with an `alt` attribute inside the button.

Comment: @Quentin I think that's a fontawesome element or similar. adding `aria-label="description"` to the wrapping <a> (or <button>) solves accessibility issues

Comment: `<a>` should be used only for navigation, this seems more like a `<button>` for me as it probably expands something. Images inside buttons shouldn't have an alt tag as their role is a presentation and they shouldn't be visible to the user. The button should have `aria-label` saying what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a button element to trigger some on-page interactivity. A link is for navigation, either to another page or an in-page anchor. You can always use CSS to remove default browser styling for buttons if needed.

In the case of a button like this that's just an icon with no text, you need an aria-label that tells non-visual users what it is.

```
<button aria-label="Open menu"> <i></i> </button>
```

See as well the W3 Design Pattern for dropdown menus for more info. https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation-hybrid.html